If $n \geq 4, \delta(G) \geq n/2, G$ contains $C_4$
Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices. Suppose furthermore that $n \geq 4$ and $\delta(G) \geq n/2.$
I want to prove that $G$ has to contain $C_4$ as a subgraph, i.e. a cycle of length $4$.
I tried to use pigeon-holing, but I'm not sure if this is the right idea: Let $v$ be any vertex of $G$. Let furthermore $u_1$ and $u_2$ be two neighboring vertices of $v$. Now, I managed to prove that if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are not connected, they have to share a common vertex, thus establishing a cycle of size $4$. However, I don't know how to fix the case when they are connected.
If this idea of proof does not work, what would be a better approach?

To use a tank to kill a mosquito : Dirac's theorem

Jokes aside : How about searching for a pair in the neighborhood that are not adjacent? What happens if you can't find any such pair?

Hmm, that could prove promising. I'll see what I can deduce, thanks!

@HackR: I don't see why a graph cannot be Hamiltonian and $C_4$-free. Am I missing a simple argument?

@PseudoNeo It was a small joke that for $n=4$, this theorem overkills.

let $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ be any two neighbours of $v$.
If $ u_{1} \sim u_2$ and $\ deg(u_{1})$ or $deg(u_{2}) > \frac{n}{2}$ then $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ have a common neighbour by Pigeonhole Principle, and hence $G$ contains $C_{4}$.
If $deg(u_{1})=deg(u_{2})=\frac{n}{2}$ then $u_{1}$ and  $u_{2}$ must each be adjacent to $\frac{n}{2}-2$ vertices from $V-\{v,u_{1},u_{2}\}$. If they have a common neighbour other than $v$, then $G$ contains $C_{4}$. If not, then there is exactly one vertex, say $l$, such that $l \nsim  u_{1}$ and $l \nsim u_{2}$.
There are exactly  $\ n-(\frac{n}{2}+1+1) = \frac{n}{2}-2 \ $ vertices other than $u_{1},l$ and neighbours of $u_{1}$. Clearly, $l$ must be adjacent to atleast $\frac{n}{2}$ vertices. Hence we conclude $l$ must be adjacent to atleast $2$ neighbours of $u_{1}$ , say $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$, hence forming cycle $u_{1},x_{1},l,x_{2}$.
And finally, if  $u_{1} \nsim  u_{2}$ then they have a common neighbour by Pigeonhole Principle hence forming a cycle.
$\blacksquare$

$a \sim b$ means $a$ is adjacent to $b$

Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was missing!
